# Update panel with a gridview causing IE script error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, gridview, updatepanel

I have an update panel that contains a GridView. When loading the panel and the GridView if the gridview has a lot of rows in it, I get an error. I only get the error in IE.

It's a warning popup that a script might be causing the page to load slowly.

I have looked around and cannot find any way to prevent this from happening. How can I prevent IE from displaying this message?

Comment: It means the script is taking a long time to execute. Is this on a fairly modern/powerful PC?

Comment: Define "lots of rows"  If we're talking hundreds (or more) then I'd suggest implementing some type of paging functionality.

Comment: This is on a fairly modern/powerful PC (developer box, core i7). As for "lots of rows" I am taking about ~1500. I know that this is a lot, but they load very quickly. I know generating that many elements would throw a warning. I was just wondering if there is any easy way to prevent that.